# Python 3.3.2 syntax error using ":" in If-else

Tags: python, python-3.3, python-idle

```
>>> x = 15
if (x/2)*2 == x:
    print ('Even')
    else:
    print ('Odd')

SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
>>> x = 15 if (x/2)*2 == x:
    print ('Even')
    else:
    print ('Odd')

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `(x/2)*2 == x` probably should be `x % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't write several statement in one line in python, write

```
x = 15 
if (x/2)*2 == x: 
   print ('Even') 
else: 
    print ('Odd')
```

here:

[image]

and got

[image]

Comment: I tried executing your code and got an error "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement"

Comment: I have compiled and ran the code and got "Odd" in output @IWantToLearn

Comment: I didn't use any script i was coding on python shell in an IDLE and i am totally confused with this, I would like to post an image for my error but unfortunately i dont have that option. @No Idea For Name

Comment: Thank you very much I figured  it out with script if you have any idea that we can directly run the same code on a shell please let me know @No Idea For Name

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* wanted to compile this down to a single statement, [you would need to have a clause for the *odd* result](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements):

```
x = 15
result = 'Even' if (x/2)*2 == x else 'Odd'; print(result)
```

but I wouldn't advise this as it's needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In the interactive interpreter, you can only ever execute a single statement at once. But you are trying to execute a whole block of code at once:

```
>>> x = 15
if (x/2)*2 == x:
    print ('Even')
else:
    print ('Odd')
```

(`>>>` indicates the interpreter prompt)

But for Python, these are two things. First the variable assignment, and then the if/else construct. So you have to do it like this:

```
>>> x = 15
>>> if (x/2)*2 == x:
    print ('Even')
else:
    print ('Odd')
```

So basically, run the `x = 15` separately first.